# struts2 and cewolf

Tags: cewolf

am getting error as **no action mapped for cewolf** while integrating struts2 with cewolf.And my chart is not getting displayed

Can anybody please help me with sample programs on struts2 and cewolf.please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post a code snippet which demonstrates the problem? Its unclear what caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to add anything to your struts-config.xml in order to use cewolf with struts. It is just a taglib which let's you use cewolf tags in your JSPs.